# What does stack[-1] mean in a pseudocode?

Tags: algorithm

```
def _all_simple_paths_graph(G, source, target, cutoff=None):
if cutoff < 1:
    return
visited = [source]
stack = [iter(G[source])]
while stack:
    children = stack[-1]
    child = next(children, None)
    if child is None:
        stack.pop()
        visited.pop()
    elif len(visited) < cutoff:
        if child == target:
            yield visited + [target]
        elif child not in visited:
            visited.append(child)
            stack.append(iter(G[child]))
    else: #len(visited) == cutoff:
        if child == target or target in children:
            yield visited + [target]
        stack.pop()
        visited.pop()
```

I find that code on this [link](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/_modules/networkx/algorithms/simple_paths.html#all_simple_paths).

But did not understand some statements, as following

- `children = stack[-1]`  // What does `stack[-1]` mean?
- `child = next(children, None)` // Is child a list or children is a list?
- `stack = [iter(G[source])]` // What is that `iter`?
- if child is None:        // Guess if child is empty (child is a list).
- `visited = [source]` // What is that?
- `yield visited + [target]` // Yield?

Can anyone explain to me? I am trying to rewrite it in C.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a python code

---

1)
`stack[-1]` means it will give the last element.

---

2)
`children` is a variable, which by this code holds the last element of the list `stack`

```
children = stack[-1]
```

`child` is whatever `next()` function returns, but by the looks of it, it also looks like a variable.

---

4)
    if child is None:
if the `next()` function returns `None`

Comment: could you explain last two line?

Comment: @alim, I think its one of the things defined by the module itself. Its not a part of the language.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not realize it is python.